# How can I call the fallback slot content from a parent component?

Tags: svelte-3

I have a Table component which has a cell slot with fallback:

```
<!-- .... -->
    <slot name="cell" {column} {columnIndex}>
        <div style="color: green">
            {column} : { cells[columnIndex] }
        </div>
    </slot>
<!-- .... -->
```

When using the Table Component I'd like to override the slot Content only for one column Index:

```
<Table columns={['a', 'b', 'c']} cells={[1, 2, 3]}>
    <div slot="cell" let:columnIndex>
        {#if columnIndex == 2 }
          3333
        {:else }
          HOW TO CALL FALLBACK OF TABLE?
        {/if}
    </div>
</Table>
```

How can i call the cell slot fallback from the Table component?

https://svelte.dev/repl/0e455d61f1db442c99a5320ce85df041?version=3.32.3

Answer (score 1):

Basically in Svelte, the slot's fallback is only called when no content is provided, in your case you are providing an element in the slot so the fallback will never gonna called.

check out this [Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/09e2859f7494400cb5ffe8a8dfbb4bf8?version=3.32.3) it shows how to achieve what you want

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't know that it's possible to put a slot as a root node in a component.

Comment: Thing is, I'd really like to call the Fallback of the Parent Component instead of replicating it.

Comment: Yeah, Svelte is cool, I really like the slot mechanism of Svelte compared with the React one